# How to create new debug adapter for unpopular programming language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm in trying to write a VS Code extension to support Atlantis Vip application development. I already have a basic grammar definition and build task, so I have syntax highlighting, and am able to build my project with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd> using the command line compiler.
To debug, I need to run a local server written in Delphi.

I tried to specify it as `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Vip Debugger",
            "type": "vip",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "MyFile.vip",
            "runtimeExecutable": "MyDebbugerPath\VipDebuggerTest.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

and:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Vip Debugger",
            "type": "vip",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "MyDebbugerPath\VipDebuggerTest.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

but in both cases, VS Code doesn't even try to launch the application.
how to launch a local application correctly?

Comment: did you see the docs? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension. Also, you don't even get an error message saying that that launch config type `vip` is not defined?

Comment: the same as you would do for a popular programming language, write some middleware that speaks Debug-Adapter and the actual debugger

Comment: @starball  I use this name in  package.json 
    {"name": "vip",
    "displayName": "vip",
    "description": "Atlantis VIP language",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.53.0" .....

Comment: @rioV8 some middleware has already been written, I can't figure out how to call it from the VSCode

Comment: did you mange to get `mock-debug` to work

Comment: in https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/example-debuggers/ in part Anatomy of the Debug Adapter package.json written "program": "./bin/gdbDebug.exe". I do the same thing, but judging by the VipDebuggerTest.exe logs, it is not called